# expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type "NSDateFormatter*"

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

```
NSString *hashKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu%lu%lu", (unsigned long)format.hash, (unsigned long)timeZone.hash, (unsigned long)locale.hash];
NSDateFormatter *formatters = [NSDate sharedDateFormatters];
NSDateFormatter *cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey];
```

I am having trouble with this line:

```
NSDateFormatter *cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey];
```

Tells me: expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type "NSDateFormatter*"

Some context:

```
    + (NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSDateFormatter *>*)sharedDateFormatters {
    static NSMutableDictionary *dict = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    });
    return dict;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the return type of your `sharedDateFormatters` method?

What data type did you declare the `formatters` variable?

See the disconnect? They need to match. You can't assign an `NSDictionary` value to a variable of type `NSDateFormatter`.

Change your line to:

```
NSDictionary *formatters = [NSDate sharedDateFormatters];
```

or:

```
NSDictionary<NSString *, NSDateFormatter *> *formatters = [NSDate sharedDateFormatters];
```