# xcode 9.3: Expected mdethod to read array element not found on object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray

Prior to xcode 9.3, the following code snippet worked fine:

```
CKRecord *thePublicGameRecord;
...
//the record value, thePublicGameRecord[KEY_PLAYERSTATES], is set to a NSMutableArray, the size of which is based on the number of players in the game.
...

for (int i = 1; i <= max_number_of_players; i++)
{
    NSNumber *playerState - thePublicGameRecord[KEY_PLAYERSTATES][i];
    ...
}
```

Since upgrading to xcode 9.3, this line:

```
NSNumber *playerState - thePublicGameRecord[KEY_PLAYERSTATES][i];
```

Now gives a build error:

> Expected method to read array element not found on object of type
>   '__kindof id < CKRecordValue > _Nullable'

and I have to unwrap the underlying array like so:

```
NSMutableArray *statesArray = thePublicGameRecord[KEY_PLAYERSTATES];
playerStatus = statesArray[i];
```

That's not the end of the world, but I preferred the original approach.

I've read many other questions reporting this error, but they all look like different scenarios (incorrect definitions of custom protocols, mismatched variable types, and/or issues prior to the release of xcode 4.5).

[Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'id<ProtocolName>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627298/expected-method-to-read-array-element-not-found-on-object-of-type-idprotocolna)

[Compiler error "expected method not found" when using subscript on NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425976/compiler-error-expected-method-not-found-when-using-subscript-on-nsarray)

[expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type "NSDateFormatter*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653654/expected-method-to-read-dictionary-element-not-found-on-object-of-type-nsdatefo?rq=1)

Since this code has been working for more than a year, I believe the error results from some change in enforcement. **In xcode 9.3, does this stem from some new/changed config setting, and can I fix it?**

Comment: How do you declare CKRecord ?

Comment: @battlmonstr `CKRecord` is from CloudKit.

Comment: `
    CKRecord *thePublicGameRecord = nil;
    id<CKRecordValue> value = thePublicGameRecord[@"something"];
    NSNumber *item = value[123];
    NSLog(@"%@", item);
    NSNumber *valueItem2 = thePublicGameRecord[@"something"][123];
    NSLog(@"%@", valueItem2);
`

this WFM without any warnings.
Are you sure you import Foundation? It needs to find that every "id" has "objectForKey:" method or something.

Comment: @battlmonstr I do have foundation.h. Your code snippet generates the same "expected method..." build error on the two lines where you used "123" as an index. So that does suggest that it's config-related, but still not sure what.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425976/compiler-error-expected-method-not-found-when-using-subscript-on-nsarray ?

Comment: That’s the middle link I cited above. Since it talks about new functionality in IOS6 and since this was working for me in IOS 11 before upgrading xcode, it doesn’t seem to be a solution for me.